# Constructing a counterexample for functions with L1 norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to disprove this statement for some functional analysis stuff, but I wasn't able to make much progress. Any advice is appreciated.

Statement:
Let $\{h_n\}$ be a series of functions belonging to $C([0,1])$ (i.e. the set of real continuous functions on $[0,1]$). Assume that the $\{h_n\}$ converges to the zero function. Then $\int_{0}^{1} |h_n(x)^2| dx$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Am I right in thinking $\{h_n\}$ converges to the zero function with respect to the $L_1$ norm?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Hint: $h_n (x) $ is $\sqrt{n}$ on the interval $[0,1/n]$ and zero otherwise. What is the $L^1$ norm of $h_n$? What about its $L^2$ norm?

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping Ameryr would fix their answer, rather than just deleting it, because they had a fine idea (and more recently, Fnacool in the comments). They defined
$$h_n = \sqrt{n} 1_{[0, 1/n]}$$
where $1_{[0, 1/n]}$ is the characteristic function on $[0, 1/n]$. That is,
$$1_{[0, 1/n]}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1/n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
The problem is that this is these functions are not continuous, and so they aren't in our space.

Consider instead the continuous piecewise linear functions
$$h_n(x) = \sqrt{n}\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2n} \\ 2 - 2nx & \text{if } \frac{1}{2n} < x < \frac{1}{n} \\ 0 & \text{if } \frac{1}{n} \le x \le 1 \end{cases}.$$
Note that
$$\sqrt{n} 1_{[0, 1/(2n)]} \le h_n \le \sqrt{n}1_{[0, 1/n]},$$
and the $1$-norm of $h_n$ converges to $0$ by squeeze theorem. However, the $2$-norm of $\sqrt{n} 1_{[0, 1/(2n)]}$ does not converge to $0$, hence the $2$-norm of $h_n$ doesn't either.

Comment: I was thinking about constructing a right triangle with base $1/n$ and height $2n$ it is the line $(h_n)^2=-2n^2x+2n=2n(1-nx)$ as $n$ goes to infinity $y$ goes to infinity and $x$ goes to zero

Comment: @Ameryr I was also thinking about something like that initially, but I decided for a trapezium because I like squeeze theorem arguments.

Comment: @Theo Bendit the construction is absolutely elegant. What was your intuition behind the problem when you first saw it?

Comment: @b_choi The discontinuous example is standard. The indicator functions over intervals produce rectanglular graphs, which are super easy to integrate. Their squares are also rectangles, and thus easy to integrate. The key is finding rectangles that become thinner and taller at the right rate. The problem is, they aren't continuous. Fortunately, we can often turn a (relatively simple) discontinuous function into a continuous function by joining up jump discontinuities with line segments, without damaging the norm much. I did so in such a way that the function was squeezed between two rectangles.